# How to add SwapChainPanel to xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is it possible to add "SwapChainPanel" view to Xamarin forms?
i have tried to use custom renderer but no success with that.

what i did:
[image]

Comment: How are we supposed to help you if you don't show us the code you're using?

Comment: you are right... i have added my renderer code, when "MYVideo" is an xamarin form grid.

Comment: please do NOT post code or errors as images.  And please post all of the relevant code - see the Help section on "How to Ask" and "MCVE"